# Why does attempting to call this module result in an "int object is not iterable" error?

Tags: python, int, iterable

I'm trying to learn how to call a function from a module in a different file.
Why does attempting to use the returned value give me an 'Int object is not iterable' error in the main?

```
import totalages



firstage = int(input('enter age: '))
secondage = int(input('enter age: '))

result = sum(firstage, secondage)

print('together you are', result, 'years old')
```

####################### This is in a separate file named totalages.py

```
def sum(a, b):

    return a + b
```

The code works as intended, to add the two inputs, when the sum function is included in the main. But if I move the function to a separate file and attempt to import the result and call it, I receive an 'int object is not iterable' error. Why?

Comment: You should tag your question with the appropriate python tags; you will get more reponses that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) is a python builtin function, so you should probably rename your function to `my_sum`

Also there are two ways to import a function

1. `from totalages import my_sum`, which tells the interpreter to go look into `totalages.py` and import the function `my_sum` and then you can directly use `my_sum(a, b)`
2. `import totalages` for which you need to do `totalages.my_sum(a,b)`

Now what happened here that your import statement did work, but you referred to the python `sum` builtin I referenced before, which accepts a iterable like a list, but since you are passing it an integer, you get the error you saw `int object is not iterable` as follows

```
In [2]: sum(1+2)                                                                                                                                      
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6576b93b138f> in <module>
----> 1 sum(1+2)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

So keeping all that in mind, your original code will change to

```
#Corrected import statement
from totalages import my_sum

firstage = int(input('enter age: '))
secondage = int(input('enter age: '))

result = my_sum(firstage, secondage)

print('together you are', result, 'years old')
```

And your totalages.py will change to

```
def my_sum(a, b):

    return a + b
```

Or the other option if you use `import totalages` is

```
import totalages

firstage = int(input('enter age: '))
secondage = int(input('enter age: '))

result = totalages.my_sum(firstage, secondage)

print('together you are', result, 'years old')
```

The output will look like:

```
enter age: 20
enter age: 30
together you are 50 years old
```

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help @Shawn ! It would be great if you could mark my answer as accepted by checking the tick next to the answer :)

Comment: Got it! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect import. With this import, the `sum` method cannot be called by `sum()` but `totalages.sum()`. You got this error message because python uses built-in method `sum`, which receive a `list` as parameter, instead of yours.

Below are some correct ways that you can use:

```py
from totalages import sum
...
sum(a, b)
```

```py
import totalages
...

totalages.sum(a, b)
```

By the way, try to avoid using same name with built-in methods. It will lead you to more confusions later on.